# Convert struct to YAML file golang, how to avoid empty quote in yaml output?

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to produce the following YAML using struct,

Expected Output:

```
all:
  hosts:
  children:
    master:
      hosts:
// This is dynamic data coming from the slice.
        192.168.99.123:
        192.168.99.125:
    worker:
      hosts:
        192.168.99.123:
        192.168.99.125:
    etcd:
      hosts:
        192.168.99.123:
        192.168.99.125:
  vars:
    ansible_user: vagrant
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

My golang struct is as follows,

```
type Inventory struct {
    All *AnsibleInventory `json:"all"`
}

// AnsibleInventory defines ansible inventory file struct
type AnsibleInventory struct {
    Hosts    string     `json:"hosts"`
    Children *HostGroup `json:"children"`
    Vars     *Vars      `json:"vars"`
}

type HostGroup struct {
    Master *Hosts `json:"master"`
    Worker *Hosts `json:"worker"`
    Etcd   *Hosts `json:"etcd"`
}

type Hosts struct {
    Hosts map[string]string `json:"hosts,omitempty"`
}

type Vars struct {
    User              string `json:"ansible_user"`
    SshPrivateKeyFile string `json:"ansible_ssh_private_key_file"`
}
```

I am initializing struct as follows,

```
    elementMap := make(map[string]string)
    for _, ip := range p.MasterIPs {
        elementMap[ip] = "" // I tried using slice this is definitely not expected 
    }

    ansibleInventory := &Inventory{
        &AnsibleInventory{Children: &HostGroup{
            Master: &Hosts{
                elementMap,
            },
            Worker: &Hosts{
                elementMap,
            },
            Etcd: &Hosts{
                elementMap,
            },
        }, Vars: &Vars{
            User:              p.Username,
            SshPrivateKeyFile: p.PrivateKeyPath,
        }}}

      b, err := yaml.Marshal(ansibleInventory)

      filename:= "/tmp/filename"

    _, err = os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(filename, b, 0644)
```

The produced output looks like this,

```
all:
  children:
    etcd:
      hosts:
// I want to avoid this empty quote 
        192.168.99.123: ""
        192.168.99.125: ""
    master:
      hosts:
        192.168.99.123: ""
        192.168.99.125: ""
    worker:
      hosts:
        192.168.99.123: ""
        192.168.99.125: ""
// Same here aovid this empty quote
  hosts: ""
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    ansible_user: vagrant
```

Comment: https://yourbasic.org/golang/sort-map-keys-values/ if your problem is sorting of children. Otherwise please describe what exactly is not right

Comment: check p.MasterIPs for carrage returns (? means its a [complex mapping key](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395) and | is a [literal style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760844) where line breaks are siginificant)

Comment: I put your code sample into a working skeleton [here](https://play.golang.org/p/MgS1FST3T1X); it produces rather different output than you claimed. Perhaps you should provide a more complete reproducer...?

Comment: Adding a carrage return to torek's [example](https://play.golang.org/p/-RCge1miaDH) makes it produce something similar to the output posted with the question.

Comment: Thank you @torek and @Brits carriage return was causing the problem which was producing extra `line and ?` element. Now I am seeing the output in `192.168.99.123: "" ` format, any idea how we can avoid extra quote. If I use slice directly instead of the map its producing list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `yaml` tag not `json` in every struct:

```golang
type Inventory struct {
    All *AnsibleInventory `yaml:"all"` // not `json:"all"`
}
```

Comment: sorry result is same

Comment: try not to ignore `err`'s and you probably will figure out why it's not working